# Change security question without calling apple

Tags: security, apple-id

I just submitted a gift card on my apple id and wanted to purchase an app. After pressing buy it asked me to enter my security questions because it's my first time and I have forgot them. I have forgot my security questions and I couldn't find a way to reset it online, apple's page says I can reset it online but it seems recently they have removed the option to reset it online and they only give you the option to call them . I wanted to ask if you guys know any way to reset security questions without calling apple.
 
Or if you know any way to purchase an app without answering security questions
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com) has all the tools you need to manage your Apple ID, including changing security questions.

Go there and log on. You will be presented with a screen that has a your Apple ID info on it. Select "Change Questions..."

[image]

You will then be prompted with the answers to your current questions. Enter them. You should now be able to change your questions.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know but the reason I'm asking this question is because I have forgotten my security questions

Comment: @m0j1 Ah, thanks for the clarification (I would add that in the body of your post as well.) If that's the case, I believe you will have to call Apple.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer of JMY1000, you can use appleid.apple.com to reset your question. Just click "Change Questions...", it will ask you for your answer, choose "Reset your security questions" and it will send an email with a link to your email address. Follow the link and reset your questions.

Comment: Seems there has been that option , but I couldn't find "Reset your security questions" anymore

Comment: you can try it on mobile broswser. I just confirmed that there's a link to reset security under "Security".

Comment: Are you sure, I just tried on the safari on my ipad and I don't see any links to reset it, it just asks for my security questions

Comment: @m0j1if you can't see "Reset your security questions" anywhere, you have to contact Apple. You can send Email or make a call to them.